# Foreign Key Constraint - (ERROR 1215). Please assist:)

Tags: mysql

I have looked at other questions on here and can't seem to find the answer I am looking for. I am attempting to make a SQL database with AUTO_INCREMENT set against the ID of each table. I have matched the data types from the foreign ID of a table to the primary key of a table. The errors occur on the following tables (only the ones that have foreign keys): NUMBERS, CUSTOMER, TRUNK, TRUNK_GROUP

The error received on these tables is:

**ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint**

Below is the code used. Wonder if anyone has any suggestions?

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `NOAS_DATABASE` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `NOAS_DATABASE` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `NOAS_DATABASE`.`IP_ADDRESSES`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `NOAS_DATABASE`.`IP_ADDRESSES` (
  `IP_ID` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `START_IP_RANGE` LONGBLOB NULL,
  `END_IP_RANGE` LONGBLOB NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IP_ID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `NOAS_DATABASE`.`NO_RANGE`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `NOAS_DATABASE`.`NO_RANGE` (
  `RANGE_ID` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENTL,
  `START_NO_RANGE` LONGBLOB NULL,
  `END_NO_RANGE` LONGBLOB NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`RANGE_ID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `NOAS_DATABASE`.`NUMBERS`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `NOAS_DATABASE`.`NUMBERS` (
  `NUM_ID` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `IP_ID` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `RANGE_ID` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `CALL_BARRING_STATUS` TEXT(10) NULL,
  `ANONYMOUS_CALL_REJECT` TEXT(20) NULL,
  `CALL_DIVERT` TEXT(20) NULL,
  `CALL_DIVERT_DEST_NO` LONGBLOB NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`NUM_ID`),
  INDEX `IP_ID_idx` (`IP_ID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `RANGE_ID_idx` (`RANGE_ID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `IP_ID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`IP_ID`)
    REFERENCES `NOAS_DATABASE`.`IP_ADDRESSES` (`IP_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `RANGE_ID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`RANGE_ID`)
    REFERENCES `NOAS_DATABASE`.`NO_RANGE` (`RANGE_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `NOAS_DATABASE`.`SERVICE`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `NOAS_DATABASE`.`SERVICE` (
  `SERVICE_ID` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SERVICE_STATUS` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `DOMAIN_NAME` LONGBLOB NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SERVICE_ID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `NOAS_DATABASE`.`CUSTOMER`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `NOAS_DATABASE`.`CUSTOMER` (
  `CUSTOMER_ID` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CUST_NETWORK_SET` TEXT(20) NULL,
  `BILLING_ID` TEXT(20) NULL,
  `LOCATION` TEXT(20) NULL,
  `SERVICE_ID` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CUSTOMER_ID`),
  INDEX `SERVICE_ID_idx` (`SERVICE_ID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `SERVICE_ID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`SERVICE_ID`)
    REFERENCES `NOAS_DATABASE`.`SERVICE` (`SERVICE_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `NOAS_DATABASE`.`NETWORK_SET`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `NOAS_DATABASE`.`NETWORK_SET` (
  `NETWORK_SET_OSS_ID` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `PRIORITY_NOAS` TEXT(20) NULL,
  `PRIORITY_SBC` TEXT(20) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`NETWORK_SET_OSS_ID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `NOAS_DATABASE`.`TRUNK_GROUP`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `NOAS_DATABASE`.`TRUNK_GROUP` (
  `TRUNK_GROUP_ID` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CUSTOMER_ID` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `TRUNK_ID` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`TRUNK_GROUP_ID`),
  INDEX `CUSTOMER_ID_idx` (`CUSTOMER_ID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `TRUNK_ID_idx` (`TRUNK_ID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `CUSTOMER_ID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`CUSTOMER_ID`)
    REFERENCES `NOAS_DATABASE`.`CUSTOMER` (`CUSTOMER_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `TRUNK_ID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`TRUNK_ID`)
    REFERENCES `NOAS_DATABASE`.`TRUNK` (`TRUNK_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `NOAS_DATABASE`.`TRUNK`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `NOAS_DATABASE`.`TRUNK` (
  `TRUNK_ID` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `TRUNK_GROUP_ID` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `NETWORK_SET_OSS_ID` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `NUM_ID` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `TRUNK_SERVICE_STATUS` TEXT(20) NULL,
  `TRUNK_GROUP_PRIORITY` TEXT(20) NULL,
  `TRUNK_CAC_LIMIT` TEXT(20) NULL,
  `HANDOVER_FORMAT` TEXT(20) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`TRUNK_ID`),
  INDEX `NETWORK_SET_OSS_ID_idx` (`NETWORK_SET_OSS_ID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `NUM_ID_idx` (`NUM_ID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `TRUNK_GROUP_ID_idx` (`TRUNK_GROUP_ID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `NETWORK_SET_OSS_ID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`NETWORK_SET_OSS_ID`)
    REFERENCES `NOAS_DATABASE`.`NETWORK_SET` (`NETWORK_SET_OSS_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `NUM_ID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`NUM_ID`)
    REFERENCES `NOAS_DATABASE`.`NUMBERS` (`NUM_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `TRUNK_GROUP_ID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`TRUNK_GROUP_ID`)
    REFERENCES `NOAS_DATABASE`.`TRUNK_GROUP` (`TRUNK_GROUP_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Please reduce that to a few relevant lines of code

Comment: Referencing fields must have the same type as the fields they reference; example: VARCHAR cannot reference INT.

Comment: `AUTO_INCREMENTL` on the `NO_RANGE ` table? Is that really in your SQL command or is it a typo?

Comment: **I have matched the data types from the foreign ID of a table to the primary key of a table.** No you haven't. Lots of your foreign keys are `VARCHAR(20)` but the primary key of the other table is `INT`.

Comment: OP - did the solution help you?

Answer (score 0):

There were minor issues in multiple tables. Here're some corrections:

**Switch to the right database**

```
USE `NOAS_DATABASE` ;
```

**IP Address table is just fine**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `IP_ADDRESSES` (
  `IP_ID` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `START_IP_RANGE` LONGBLOB NULL,
  `END_IP_RANGE` LONGBLOB NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IP_ID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

**No Range table**

There was a type in AUTO_INCREMENT as commentor Dan mentioned. Below is the corrected version.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `NO_RANGE` (
  `RANGE_ID` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, -- fixed typo
  `START_NO_RANGE` LONGBLOB NULL,
  `END_NO_RANGE` LONGBLOB NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`RANGE_ID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

**Numbers had datatype issues**

IP_ID and Range_ID should be INT. That's been corrected as follows.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `NUMBERS` (
  `NUM_ID` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `IP_ID` INT(10) NULL,  -- fixed datatype
  `RANGE_ID` INT(10) NULL, -- fixed datatype
  `CALL_BARRING_STATUS` TEXT(10) NULL,
  `ANONYMOUS_CALL_REJECT` TEXT(20) NULL,
  `CALL_DIVERT` TEXT(20) NULL,
  `CALL_DIVERT_DEST_NO` LONGBLOB NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`NUM_ID`),
  INDEX `IP_ID_idx` (`IP_ID` ASC),
  INDEX `RANGE_ID_idx` (`RANGE_ID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `IP_ID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`IP_ID`)
    REFERENCES `IP_ADDRESSES` (`IP_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `RANGE_ID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`RANGE_ID`)
    REFERENCES `NO_RANGE` (`RANGE_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

**Service table is good**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `SERVICE` (
  `SERVICE_ID` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SERVICE_STATUS` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `DOMAIN_NAME` LONGBLOB NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SERVICE_ID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

**Customer table had datatype issue**

Service_ID should be an INT. Corrected below.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CUSTOMER` (
  `CUSTOMER_ID` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CUST_NETWORK_SET` TEXT(20) NULL,
  `BILLING_ID` TEXT(20) NULL,
  `LOCATION` TEXT(20) NULL,
  `SERVICE_ID` INT(10) NULL,  -- fixed datatype
  PRIMARY KEY (`CUSTOMER_ID`),
  INDEX `SERVICE_ID_idx` (`SERVICE_ID` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `SERVICE_ID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`SERVICE_ID`)
    REFERENCES `SERVICE` (`SERVICE_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

**Network set is good**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `NETWORK_SET` (
  `NETWORK_SET_OSS_ID` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `PRIORITY_NOAS` TEXT(20) NULL,
  `PRIORITY_SBC` TEXT(20) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`NETWORK_SET_OSS_ID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

**Trunk group had reference to a table that wasn't yet created**

Trunk table was not created yet and Trunk_Group was referring to it. Removed that reference. Consider the possibility of removing trunk_id from trunk_group field.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TRUNK_GROUP` (
  `TRUNK_GROUP_ID` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CUSTOMER_ID` INT(10) NULL,
  `TRUNK_ID` INT(10) NULL, -- consider removing this field
  PRIMARY KEY (`TRUNK_GROUP_ID`),
  INDEX `CUSTOMER_ID_idx` (`CUSTOMER_ID` ASC) ,
  INDEX `TRUNK_ID_idx` (`TRUNK_ID` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `CUSTOMER_ID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`CUSTOMER_ID`)
    REFERENCES `CUSTOMER` (`CUSTOMER_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION 
    -- removed trunk_id reference to trunk
    )
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

**Trunk table's datatypes were fixed**

Trunk_Group_ID and Network_Set_OSS_ID were switched to INT.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TRUNK` (
  `TRUNK_ID` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `TRUNK_GROUP_ID` INT(10) NULL, -- fixed datatype
  `NETWORK_SET_OSS_ID` INT(10) NULL, -- fixed datatype
  `NUM_ID` INT(10) NULL,
  `TRUNK_SERVICE_STATUS` TEXT(20) NULL,
  `TRUNK_GROUP_PRIORITY` TEXT(20) NULL,
  `TRUNK_CAC_LIMIT` TEXT(20) NULL,
  `HANDOVER_FORMAT` TEXT(20) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`TRUNK_ID`),
  INDEX `NETWORK_SET_OSS_ID_idx` (`NETWORK_SET_OSS_ID` ASC) ,
  INDEX `NUM_ID_idx` (`NUM_ID` ASC) ,
  INDEX `TRUNK_GROUP_ID_idx` (`TRUNK_GROUP_ID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `NETWORK_SET_OSS_ID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`NETWORK_SET_OSS_ID`)
    REFERENCES `NETWORK_SET` (`NETWORK_SET_OSS_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `NUM_ID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`NUM_ID`)
    REFERENCES `NUMBERS` (`NUM_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `TRUNK_GROUP_ID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`TRUNK_GROUP_ID`)
    REFERENCES `TRUNK_GROUP` (`TRUNK_GROUP_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

**Avoid circular references**

Trunk group and trunk were referring to each other. I'd recommend that you have the relationship for Trunk such that Trunk belongs to a Trunk group and just keep it at that. I also removed the `visible` keyword.

I ran this on MySQL 5.7 and it worked well.